# Jenkins pipeline files present in sh blocks not present in later steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Here is my stage block

```
stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing ${env.JOB_NAME}:${env.BUILD_ID} on ${env.JENKINS_URL}..'
                sh """
                    docker run -v /tmp/work/report:/report ${env.REPO}:${env.BUILD_ID} ./manage.py jenkins --enable-coverage --output-dir=/report
                    ls /work/report
                    cat /work/report/*.xml
                """
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: '/work/report/*.xml'
                // junit '/work/report/*.xml'
            }
        }
```

The files are present in the 'sh' block, as the output of the ls and cat show.  However, in the next step 'archiveArtifacts' and (if I enable it) junit, the files are not found.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are [mounting the local folder `/tmp/work/report` to `/report`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume), but then you are testing `/work/report`

Also make sure to test it outside a pipeline, doing the docker run manually: when the container exit, it might reset its content.